# How can I fix this error (CS0102) in Unity 2d

Tags: c#

[image]
So I am creating my first game in unity. I am currently working on the left to right movement and getting error:

> CS0102

Answer (score 0):

I assume your class inherits from another (if not, please paste your whole class into your question). The error means that `CrossPlatformInputManager` is already defined in the class you inherited from, and you're trying to define it again.

You have two options:

1. Just delete that line.
2. If you really want to override it, mark it with the `new` keyword.

In the future, please paste your code and the errors into your question, rather than using images. Your image is very hard to read, and it makes it harder to answer your question because we can't copy the error message or your code ourselves.